# Android In-App-Billing development from non supported country

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-pay

I am a developer from a country that is not on the list of supported countries for Google Wallet merchant account. But my client for which I am developing application lives in a country that is on a supported list.

What should I do? I cannot test In-App-Billing I have implemented, or anything else with it.. also I cannot send app like this.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news is you cannot test it because your merchant account in registered in a country, which Google does not support. If you can find someone, who can register a test merchant account in supported country for you, then you can start testing with this account.